# PHP: Multi cUrl stopped working overnight with no error

Tags: php

Here is my code below:

```
public function multiCurl($function,$type,$from,$to) {
    try{

        if (!function_exists("\curl_init")){
            \load_curl();
        }

        echo 'FUNCTION: '.$function.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'TYPE: '.$type.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'FROM: '.$from.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'TO: '.$to.PHP_EOL;

        $multiCurl = array();
        $result = array();
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        for ($x = $from; $x <=$to; $x++) {
          $fetchURL = 'https://example.org/cc/AjaxMyProcess/'.$function.'/'.$x.'/'.$type;
          $multiCurl[$x] = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($multiCurl[$x], CURLOPT_URL,$fetchURL);
          curl_setopt($multiCurl[$x], CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
          curl_setopt($multiCurl[$x], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
          curl_setopt($multiCurl[$x], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
          curl_setopt($multiCurl[$x], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($multiCurl[$x], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 600);
          curl_setopt($multiCurl[$x], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        600);
          curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $multiCurl[$x]);
        }
        $index=null;
        do {
          curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
        } while($index > 0);
        foreach($multiCurl as $k => $ch) {
          $result[$k] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
          curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
        }
        curl_multi_close($mh);
        print_r($result);

    }

    catch ( \Exception $err ){
        echo "<br><b>Exception</b>: line ".__LINE__.": ".$err->getMessage()."</br>";
    }
}
```

I run it as below

```
multiCurl('workcsv','normal',10,20)
```

The output is:

```
FUNCTION: workCsv
TYPE: normal
FROM: 60
TO: 70

Array
(
    [60] => 
    [61] => 
    [62] => 
    [63] => 
    [64] => 
    [65] => 
    [66] => 
    [67] => 
    [68] => 
    [69] => 
    [70] => 
)
```

However the workcsv function being called does not run. If I go to https://example.org/cc/AjaxMyProcess/workcsv/60/normal manually, I get lots of debugging information and I can see that the process has run.

However running it with the above, it doesn't seem to run.

It was working up to this morning where I have come in and it's failing to run.

Any idea?

Comment: Calling these URLs manually in your browser can be seen as an indicator that there is no general error on that end - but it doesn’t _proof_ anything in regard to your actual cURL requests. Are these target URLs under your control as well? Then I’d rather start debugging things from that end maybe.

Comment: what's in your `error_log` ? any warnings, errors, notices, deprecations, anything? set error_reporting to -1